# Creating new String with sorted letters from a String word in Java

Tags: java, string, character, alphabetical, sorting

How do I create a String with alphabetical order letters taken from another String?

Let's say I have something like this

```
String theWord = "Hello World";
```

How do I compute the new String to make it look like"

> dehllloorw

Which is theWord but sorted character by character in alphabetical order.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far? What do you think is the core logic to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
char[] chars = theWord.toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars);
String newWord = new String(chars);
```

Comment: Another homework assignment completed by Stack Overflow, in 4 minutes.

Comment: @Paul that's part of my job security scheme. By keeping future developers from thinking about their problems I also keep them from improving and eliminate potential competition :-)

Answer (score 10):

See [`Arrays.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) & [`toCharArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29)

Answer (score 4):

Agreed, I stole the solution. But apparently, it's also important to strip whitespace and make everything lowercase:

```
char[] array = theWord.replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase().toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(array);
System.out.println(new String(array));
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above solutions are locale specific , therefore I came with this solution, it is not efficient , but it works very well..

```
public static String localeSpecificStringSort(String str, Locale locale) {

        String[] strArr = new String[str.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            strArr[i] =  str.substring(i,i+1);
        }
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
        Arrays.sort(strArr, collator);
        StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();
        for (String string : strArr) {
            strBuf.append(string);
        }
        return strBuf.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char[] arr = new char[theWord.length()];
for(int i=0;i<theWord.length;i++)
{
    arr[i]=theWord.charAt(i);
}
for(int i=0;i<theWord.length();i++)
  for(int j=0;j<theWord.length();j++)
{
    char temp = arr[i];
    arr[i]=arr[j];
    arr[j]=temp;
}
int size=theWord.length();
theWord="";
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    theWord+=arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

// re arrange alphabets in order
public class RearrangeAlphabets {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String theWord;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string to rearrange: \n");

        theWord = in.nextLine();
        int length = theWord.length();
        System.out.println("Length of string: "+length);
        char[] chars=theWord.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chars);
        String newWord=new String(chars);

        System.out.println("The Re-Arranged word : "+newWord);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char[]  chars2  = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
Arrays.sort(chars1);
String  Ns1   = new String(chars1);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions were O(nlogn) as they are sorting the array. Instead we can take array[26] and do this in O(n).
after you covert it into lowercase and remove spaces which are O(n),
int[] ar=new int[26];
for(char c:s.toCharArray()) ar[c-'a']++;
 and then form the required string O(n).